# Centrar mensaje con session->flash() en Laravel

Tags: html, css

me gustaría saber cómo centrar un mensaje hecho con `session->flash()` Los mensajes salen arriba a la derecha.

Esta es la sentencia que uso:

```
$request->session()->flash('ajaxSuccess', trans('Contenido del mensaje'));
```

En HTML he probado esto

```
 <div justify-content-center>
      @if (session('status'))
          <div class="alert alert-success"
               role="alert">
                {{ session('status') }}
          </div>
      @endif
...
</div>
```

Pero ni caso.

Tengo una captura del inspector de elementos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si observáis hay una clase, `iziToast-wrapper-topRight` que es la que fastidia todo, creo.

Gracias.

Comment: Agrega tu html.

Comment: Para centrar en el mensaje tendras que editarlo en tu blade o html de tu views

Comment: La única manera que he encontrado, hasta ahora, es la de modificar la clase '...-topRight' en el app.scss y ponerle 'text-align:center" y 'top: 50%' para que lo centre en pantalla. Pero es una chapuzilla que no me gusta.